# Ruby 1.8.7 each_with_index index offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-enterprise-edition

How can i specify which index to start from when using `each_with_index` on a collection in ruby 1.8.7?

```
collection.each_with_index do |element, index = 1|
  #do smth
end
```

Using it like this gives the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
collection.each_with_index do |element, i = 1|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
collection[4..-1].each_with_index do |element, index|
  #do smth
end
```

this example will start from fifth element.

Comment: Well, that is not exactly what i need. I need the index to start with `1`, `index` is used further in block.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? For example you have array ['a', 'b','c','d']. You want to start from element 'b'? Or you want to have first index for example 1 not 0?

Comment: I guess the author just needs `method_that_uses_index(index+1)` :)

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6].drop(3).each_with_index {|e,i|p e;p i}`is an alternative.